# Visual Studio 2019 SQL reporting services - save as window is opened when I click preview tab

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, microsoft-reporting, sqlreportingservice

I created new report in Visual Studio 2019 using Microsoft Reporting Services. I added data connection, created dataset and inserted table into report designer. When I click on Preview tab, "Save File As" windows is opened, and the preview is not showing. Even when I save the project and click on Preview tab again, same thing happends. Any suggestion what could be the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: what file type is it asking you to save, *.rdl?

Comment: Hello Alan, it is asking to save *.rptproj file.

Comment: OK, so that's just the report project file that contains all the RDL files. May sound obvious but have you actually saved the project file yet? The normal hierarchy for an SSRS report, even jus a single one is. Visual Studio solution (.sln), SSRS Project (.rptproj) then finally, the report definition (.rdl). Just hit the save all button on he toolbar, save everything and then try to preview again.

Comment: I was using VS 2019. I was given an advice to try reinstalling to 2017 and it made it work.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using VS 2019. I was given an advice to try reinstalling to 2017 and it made it work.